# Can a class implement some logic for when it's checked by empty()?

Tags: php, class

I have a class that contains a bunch of averages, but if there is no data all the fields will be `NULL`, and in the eyes of my logic, "empty". However, wrapping my class in `if(empty($myClassInstance))` returns false, which is correct, but I was wondering if there is any magic methods in PHP where I could say "If this objected is checked for being empty, do some stuff and return a bool"?

I realise I can add a `isEmpty()` method, I am just curious if this is something that can be done.

Comment: You could always have a quick squint at [The Manual for MAGIC METHODS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: You could potentially loop over the class properties with [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), check if any of them is `empty` or whatever it is you wish to check for and return.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I had a look there and didn't see anything that seemed like it would do what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok despite my thought to use __toString(), I suggest strongly to use a semantical correct and transparent method. There is no working magic method for your use case and it's not transparent to use magic at all.

Comment: I know there is nothing you can use. But now you checked that manual so do you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
The following things are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```